# Replace Nth CSV field where first field match string Bash

Tags: bash, csv, replace, sed

I'm trying to replace the content of a csv field based on the first one. I tried something with sed - found in another thread - but I'm unable to obtain a proper result.

Example :

```
57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2;510;1020;20130410
4858ecf7bf221fd8a3792615d8008dd8;530;4050;20130412
```

I want to be able to replace field content based on its number and where the first field contain "57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2".

My current sed line work only for the last field :

```
sed -i 's/\(57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2\)\(;.*;\).*/\1\220130401/' myfile
```

Comment: Please explain the question clearly. If possible, post expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to replace  third and last field(if `;` is a delimiter) with the number `20130401`,

```
$ sed 's/^\(57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2\)\(;[^;]*;\).*$/\1\220130401/g' file
57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2;510;20130401
4858ecf7bf221fd8a3792615d8008dd8;530;4050;20130412
```

Answer (score 0):

May this be ok?

```
awk -F\; '$1=="57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2" {$NF=220130401}1' OFS=\; file
57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2;510;1020;220130401
4858ecf7bf221fd8a3792615d8008dd8;530;4050;20130412
```

If first field is `57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2` replace last field to `220130401`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^;]*/xxx/2' file
```

This replaces the second field with `xxx`.

If you want the second field of a particular line, use:

```
sed '/57c5b4da8ef722a0d4b0bbd9727982d2/s/[^;]*/2' file
```